# Why did my smog check cost so much?

Tags: emissions

I have a 1991 Cadillac Eldorado and had to go to a Star Certified test station for a DMV-required biennial smog check. The technician gave me the price up front and I said that was a lot. He said the cost was $25.00 more than the regular price because he had to use a dynamometer. Was I taken advantage of?

Comment: going back to early 90s models they (GM especially) built specific California emissions models for cars to be sold in CA with the proper interface for testing. It may be the case you have a non-CA version.  My opinion if you passed the dyno smog check be happy!

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think you were taken advantage of. But with the newer vehicles, 2000 and up(maybe) and under a certain gvwr only need to have the obd II monitors pass. To check it only requires hooking up to the obd II connector. Which takes way less time. So older cars will require more work to perform the smog. Thus the higher charge.